# is there a straightforward way for a c# application to read a config file with a user specified name and location

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files

we have an application suite that consists of a half dozen services which processes data in a static folder hierarchy.  the current rules for app.config files make managing this environment a difficult task.

i have gone down the OpenExeConfiguration and can't get past a type initializer error.

i have gone down the create your own AppDomain path and can't get past assembly not flagged as serialiazable.

the current codebase contains a custom config file that uses the xsd --> xml, create a custom class where each parameter is its own class and that is a nightmare to maintain.

so, the basic need is to tell ConfigurationManager, at location xxx you will find a file named zzz.config.  When i call ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["parametername"] i want you to return the value in the file that is associated with parametername.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try something like this:

```
        ExeConfigurationFileMap m = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        m.ExeConfigFilename = "blah";
        ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(m, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Note that I didn't test that, but it might put you on the right track.